# Reactjs Styled-components not working properly

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

I have a styled checkbox and I want to set its background to white when `checked:false` and to green when `checked:true`

But the problem is background color is always staying green and i dont know why.

The react component in which I'm using this checkbox component is acting right,Its just background color that i cant adjust

Any suggestions please?

```
    const CheckboxContainer = styled.div`
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
`

const Icon = styled.svg`
  fill: none;
  stroke: white;
  stroke-width: 2px;
`

const HiddenCheckbox = styled.input.attrs({ type: 'checkbox' })`
  border: 0;
  clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
  clippath: inset(50%);
  height: 1px;
  margin: -1px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 1px;
`

const StyledCheckbox = styled.div`
  display: inline-block;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  background: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 3px;
  transition: all 150ms;
  margin-top: 10px;

  ${HiddenCheckbox}:focus + & {
    background: ${({ checked }) => (checked ? '#06ba63' : '#ffffff')};
  }

  ${Icon} {
    visibility: ${({ checked }) => (checked ? 'visible' : 'hidden')};
  }
`

const Checkbox = ({ className, checked, ...props }) => (
  <CheckboxContainer className={className}>
    <HiddenCheckbox checked={checked} {...props} />
    <StyledCheckbox checked={checked}>
      <Icon viewBox="0 0 24 24">
        <polyline points="20 6 9 17 4 12" />
      </Icon>
    </StyledCheckbox>
  </CheckboxContainer>
)

export default Checkbox
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should check for `checked` instead of `focus` of the checkbox :

```
${HiddenCheckbox}:checked + & {
    background: ${({ checked }) => (checked ? '#06ba63' : '#ffffff')};
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If both `Hidden` and `Styled` checkboxes are get the same value from `checked`, you only need to use the value of `checked` passed to `StyledCheckbox` (like you do with Icon):

```
const StyledCheckbox = styled.div`
  display: inline-block;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  background: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 3px;
  transition: all 150ms;
  margin-top: 10px;

  background: ${({ checked }) => (checked ? '#06ba63' : '#ffffff')};

  ${Icon} {
    visibility: ${({ checked }) => (checked ? 'visible' : 'hidden')};
  }
`
```

The other option is only to apply the style if `HiddenCheckbox` is checked via CSS selectors:

```
const StyledCheckbox = styled.div`
  display: inline-block;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  background: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 3px;
  transition: all 150ms;
  margin-top: 10px;
  
  background: white;
  ${Icon} {
    visibility: hidden;
  }

  ${HiddenCheckbox}:checked + & {
    background: #06ba63;
  }

  ${HiddenCheckbox}:checked + & > ${Icon} {
    visibility: visible;
  }
`
```